# Change which html code to use on mobile device

Tags: html, joomla, joomla3.0

I am trying to embed an Instagram slideshow widget onto my Joomla site using a custom HTML module. I would like to modify the size of the slideshow widget dependent on whether the user is on a mobile device or a desktop/notebook. Is this possible?

The widget I'm trying to use is from SnapWidget, and their HTML looks like this (I've hidden the source for anonymity of the Instagram account):

```
<iframe src="http://snapwidget.com/sl/..." width="505px" height="505px" class="snapwidget-widget" style="border: none; overflow: hidden; width: 505px; height: 505px;" title="Instagram Widget" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear - the question is is it possible to use HTML/something in Joomla!/anything else to determine whether or not something is displayed based on the resolution of the user's device?

Answer (score 0):

Just add **MEDIA QUERIES** to **style.css** of the template :

```css
@media (max-width: 644px) {
  iframe {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```